# How can this Python script be changed such that it sets Ubuntu shortkeys successfully?

Tags: python, ubuntu, key-bindings

I am attempting to get a Python script working that is designed to set Ubuntu shortkeys. It does not appear to be working in Ubuntu 16.10 and I am unsure why. In addition, I am finding it difficult to keep track of the quotation marks and their respective escapes needed for commands, strings, Bash etc.

The script is designed to be used in a way like the following:

```
./set_Ubuntu_shortkey.py                                                               \
    --command="bash -c \"xvkbd -text \$(date \"+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ\" --utc) 2>/dev/null\"" \
    --name="type_time_UTC"                                                             \
    --keys="<Control><Shift>d"
```

This should ideally then set the Ubuntu shortkey such that it has the following characteristics:

- name: `type_time_UTC`
- command: `bash -c "xvkbd -text $(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ" --utc) 2>/dev/null"`
- key-bindings: `Ctrl+Shift+D`

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
################################################################################
#                                                                              #
# set_Ubuntu_shortkey                                                          #
#                                                                              #
################################################################################

usage:
    program [options]

options:
    -h, --help      display help message
    --version       display version and exit
    --command=TEXT  command
    --keys=TEXT     keys
    --name=TEXT     name
    --debugpassive  display commands without executing
"""

import docopt
import logging
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time

def main(options):

    command       = options["--command"]
    keys          = options["--keys"]
    name          = options["--name"]
    debug_passive = options["--debugpassive"]

    if None in [command, keys, name]:
        print("insufficient options specified")
        exit()

    print("\nset shortkey:"          )
    print("- name:    " + name       )
    print("- command: " + command    )
    print("- keys:    " + keys + "\n")

    shortkeys_current     = subprocess.check_output([
                               "gsettings",
                               "get",
                               "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys",
                               "custom-keybindings"
                            ]).decode("utf-8")
    if shortkeys_current.strip() == "@as []":
        shortkeys_current = "[]"
    shortkeys_current     = eval(shortkeys_current)
    index_shortkey_new    = len(shortkeys_current)
    address_shortkey_new  =\
        "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/" +\
        "custom" + str(index_shortkey_new) + "/"
    shortkeys_current.append(
        address_shortkey_new
    )

    command_list_1 = [
        "gsettings",
        "set",
        "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:" +\
            address_shortkey_new,
        "name",
        name
    ]
    command_list_2 = [
        "gsettings",
        "set",
        "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:" +\
            address_shortkey_new,
        "command",
        command
    ]
    command_list_3 = [
        "gsettings",
        "set",
        "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:" +\
            address_shortkey_new,
        "binding",
        keys
    ]

    if debug_passive:
        print(" ".join(command_list_1))
        print(" ".join(command_list_2))
        print(" ".join(command_list_3))
    else:
        subprocess.Popen(command_list_1)
        subprocess.Popen(command_list_2)
        subprocess.Popen(command_list_3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
    if options["--version"]:
        print(version)
        exit()
    main(options)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `if any([command, keys, name]) is None` doesn't make any sense. `any(...)` returns a boolean, and a boolean will never be `None`.

Comment: @Rawing Thanks for spotting that. I've updated it to something more sensible (`if None in [command, keys, name]`).